# aspboilerplate multi-tenant configuration using {0}.domain.com format

Tags: asp.net-core, aspnetboilerplate

I downloaded the latest [aspboilerplate](https://aspnetboilerplate.com). In [documentation](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Multi-Tenancy#ignore-feature-check-for-host-users)
it lists 3 tenant resolvers.

document ask to add;

```
Configuration.Modules.AbpWebCommon().MultiTenancy.DomainFormat = "{0}.mydomain.com";
```

to get domain based tenant resolving.

I am using hosts file to simulate actual URLs. So, I feel the app config should be something like below (apart from above code change to Abp module);

```
"App": {
    "ServerRootAddress": "http://server.mydomain.com",
    "ClientRootAddress": "http://{0}.mydomain.com",
    "CorsOrigins": "...."
},
```

But the documentation doesn't mention anything related to that. So, I don't think the documentation is complete.

Then in IIS, I have two sites.

1. API site : server.mydomain.com. Bindings set to server.mydomain.com
2. Client site : mydomain.com. A new binding will be added such as subdomain.mydomain.com for new tenant(s). So basically in IIS for client site there can be many bindings with different subdomains portion, but pointing to the same site.

Then I ran the api site **xxxx.web.host.exe**. I assume it should pick the correct urls to listen to from appsettings. But it doesn't. it shows;

```
Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
```

And I am not sure where its coming from since there is no reference to that in code.

How can I get this properly configured to run on IIS with subdomain based tenant resolver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actual issue(s) were outside of what I have thought. In brief;

1. https://edi.wang/post/2018/12/27/path-caveat-with-aspnet-core-22-iis-hosting is one issue which crashed the app at the very beginning. Reason is it was loading log4net config file at Startup() and because of the way asp.net core 2.2 works, in IIS inproc mode it can't find the file.
2. https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2019/Mar/16/ASPNET-Core-Hosting-on-IIS-with-ASPNET-Core-22 this helped a lot to understand and tackle the issue.
3. Make sure you don't mix 32bit 64bit when hosting in IIS.